# Select by date in attribute table using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, select, date

I want to select attributes by date, but ignore the minutes, seconds, etc. I've commented out some of the lines below and am just experimenting with hard-coded values.

The arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer() line worked with one shapefile that I'd imported from QGIS into ArcGIS Pro, where I am now working. The Date column in this file was a "TEXT" type column, and the date format was yyyy/mm/dd. I altered the format of the date in my SQL statement to accommodate a layer that I built in ArcGIS Online (data entered via the Field Maps app), but this line now kicks out an "ERROR 160195: An invalid SQL statement was used" message. I'm wondering if this has something to do with the Date column now being a "DATE" type column.

Based on this assumption, my workaround was to create a column called Date2, give it the data type "TEXT," and try to copy the info over from the original Date column - then see if arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer() would work with the Date2 column. However, this approach is kicking out this error: "ERROR 160327: A column was specified that does not exist." The Date column does exist (no space in the column title or anything).

I also tried arcpy.management.AlterField() at one point to alter the original Date field’s data type, but I got the "column does not exist" error there as well.

I need this script to work with the data that will be coming in via the Field Maps app. Can anyone recommend an approach that would work?

```
import arcpy
import datetime
from datetime import date

# set input layer & date
# inputLayer = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
# inputDate = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
# output = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

inputLayer = 'Daily Reports Test'
inputDate = '5/13/2023'
# output = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

arcpy.management.CalculateField(inputLayer, 'Date2', 'Date')

#inputDate formatting
inputDateTwo = datetime.datetime.strptime(inputDate, "%m/%d/%Y")
inputDatePlusDay = inputDateTwo + datetime.timedelta(days=1)

# convert date to hyphen format for use in output file names
tempDateTwo = datetime.datetime.strptime(inputDate, "%m/%d/%Y").strftime('%m-%d-%Y')

#set project and map variables
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject('CURRENT')
m = aprx.listMaps('*')[0]

# selects by expression and creates a new layer from selected dates in inputLayer   
newLayer = arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer(inputLayer, tempDateTwo, 'Date >= \''+format(inputDateTwo.strftime("%#m/%d/%Y"))+'\' AND Date < \''+format(inputDatePlusDay.strftime("%#m/%d/%Y"))+'\'').getOutput(0)
m.addLayer(newLayer)
```

If this helps, when I print the SQL statements, they appear like this:

original script, working with the imported QGIS file:

```
 Date >= '2023/05/13' AND Date < '2023/05/14'
```

Updated script, working with the ArcGIS Pro file:

```
 Date >= '5/13/2023' AND Date < '5/14/2023'
```

Comment: Yes, dates are tricky, have a read of https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-layers/sql-reference-for-query-expressions-used-in-arcgis.htm#GUID-85C03D85-F4A5-48FC-8E8C-3F79919430DB when querying a date field in a shapefile preceed the literal date string with *date*, for example *"Datefield" = date 'yyyy-mm-dd'* if that doesn't sort it out populate a field of type long integer with **int(YYYYmmdd)** (python syntax), you should be able to query a range properly with this numeric representation of date.

Comment: Shapefile doesn't even support time in dates. dBase does define (amazingly, in the pre-Y2K era) dates as `YYYYMMDD`. I'd recommend using ISO formatting (`date 'YYYY-MM-DD'`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was caused by something really simple: the field I listed in my SQL expression. I was using the Display Name for the field, not the actual field name - Date vs DateTaken. Leaving this up in case it helps someone.